# Mercurial Merge Take Local/Ignore Remote Completely

Tags: mercurial, merge

I was wondering if this is possible.

Let's say I have the following changesets

```
Changeset 5: Did Something to file c.txt
Changeset 4: Added some change to File b.txt
Changeset 3: Added some change to File a.txt
Changeset 2: Did Something to file c.txt
Changeset 1: Did Something to file c.txt
```

I realized that from changeset 3 to 5, I messedup and I want to go back to changeset 2 [Easily done with an update].

Now I work off of Changeset 2 and I make changeset 6, which has the parent of changeset2.

If I merge Changeset 2 into Changeset 5, The changes to file b.txt and file a.txt will show up in the merged heads. Is there a way to just make changeset 6 my new head?

A couple of constraints. I don't want to start a new branch, and I cannot strip the changes since they are already pushed to the server.

Comment: You should be able to accomplish this by closing the anonymous branch ending in changeset 5 with `hg update -r <id of changeset 5>; hg commit --close-branch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- backout 3 and 4 in changeset 7
- merge 6 and 7